# Order by joined table data

Tags: mysql

Here is my tables:

*topics*

```
topic_id    name
1           "Help!"
2           "Hey!"
3           "What?"
```

*posts*

```
post_id    topic    date        content
1          2        2016-05-01  "Hey there!"
2          1        2016-05-04  "How to use WIFI?"
3          1        2016-05-05  "I dont know"
4          1        2016-05-02  "What is WIFI?"
5          3        2016-05-06  "What what?"
6          2        2016-05-02  "Hello"
```

I have this code

```
SELECT * from topics
LEFT JOIN posts
ON posts.topic = topics.topic_id
```

I want to join the **posts** with last (most recent) record only, and sort the records from **topics** by **posts.date**,
but I don't how to.

Expected result:

```
topic_id    post_id   date          ...
3           5         2016-05-06    ...
1           3         2016-05-05    ...
2           6         2016-05-02    ...
```

Comment: How is ... expected?

Answer (score 2):

Please try this Query

```
SELECT * from topics LEFT JOIN posts ON posts.topic = topics.topic_id
Left join (Select posts.topics, Max(posts.date) as Date From posts Group by posts.topics) as postgroup
on posts.date = postgroup.date and posts.topic = postgroup.topics;
```

Answer (score 1):

Let me assume that `post_id` defines the last record.  You can do this in various ways.  Here is a method using `WHERE` and a correlated subquery:

```
SELECT * 
FROM topics t LEFT JOIN
     posts p
     ON p.topic = t.topic_id
WHERE p.post_id = (SELECT MAX(p2.post_id) FROM posts p2 WHERE p2.topic = p.topic)
ORDER BY p.post_date DESC;
```

Comment: You missed the `order by` clause, aren't you ?

Comment: @wajeeh . . . Yes, I see that the OP does want the results ordered by date.

Comment: If i want posts.date defines the last record, how to?